# does the Myth of Sisyphus illustrate dasein?

Tags: heidegger, camus

In the brief illustration provided by Camus we see a man pushing a stone and accepting his lot. As the stone rolls back down the hill it seems he is able to remove himself from this plight, much like a person applying the personal attributions given by Heidegger's Being and Time. Could Camus be seeing a similar dasein-like essence that Heidegger points out?

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "the personal attributions given by Heidegger's Being and Time".

Comment: "dasein-like essence that Heidegger points out"; essence of what thing? Dasein itself has an essence. Heidegger: "The 'essence' of dasein lies in its existence" (Das »Wesen« des Dasein liegt in seiner Existenz). Dasein's essence is its thrown openness.

Comment: i'm all for these, challenging, sorts of questions which ask about overlap between different thinkers, especially the existentialists. you have e.g. harr "Dasein henceforth appears as the intimate essence of man" @Enowning

Comment: If [Dadein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasein) "is always a being engaged in the world: neither a subject, nor the objective world alone, but the coherence of [Being-in-the-world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heideggerian_terminology#Being-in-the-world)" we can link it to Camus' [Myth of Sisyphus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus) : 1/2

Comment: "Camus states that "It is during that return, that pause, that S interests me[...] I see that man going back down with a heavy yet measured step toward the torment of which he will never know the end." This is the truly tragic moment, when the hero becomes conscious of his wretched condition. He does not have hope. Acknowledging the truth will conquer it; S, just like the absurd man, keeps pushing. Camus claims that when S acknowledges the futility of his task and the certainty of his fate, he is freed to realize the absurdity of his situation and to reach a state of contented acceptance." 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's the point I was making, thank you. If I needed to word it better please make suggestions.

Comment: @user3293056 Thank you for your wisdom.